# DevOps work item created email notification issue-Too many emails

Tags: azure-devops, devops

So I want to receive email notification when a work item is created. And I do receive email notification when a new work item is created. The issue is, I get email every time I change something in the work item.
Any idea to receive email notification only once the very first time?

[DevOps Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FojS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you may receive the notifications for work item changed when meeting any of the following situations:

1. The work item that has been assigned to you. This is aiming to prevent you from missing any important changes on the work item.
2. You are following the work item. If you are following a work item, by default you will receive the notifications for any changes on this work item. However, you can custom notifications of the followed work item clicking the [image] gear icon so that you can only receive the notifications for specified changes. You can select the option "**Not Subscribed**" or "**Custom**". For more details, you can see "[Follow a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/follow-work-items?view=azure-devops#follow-a-work-item)".

   [image]
3. Someone has added the notification "**A work item is changed**", and you are a member of the roles that this notification will be delivered to. You can go to "**Project Settings**" > "**Notifications**" to check this and try to disable or delete this notification. Or remove yourself from the roles. For more details, you can see "[About notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops)".

   [image]